# Stripping section header of shared library in Android

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, elf, strip

I have a Java + NDK project on Android with `CMakeLists.txt` file for the shared library and I want to strip section headers of the .so file. I used `sstrip` and some other tools by adding as `POST_BUILD` using `add_custom_command` in the `CMakeLists.txt` file. After the compilation I see that the patcher (sstrip etc) works properly, but I get an error like `lib.so: File truncated` and the App does not run at all because it cannot load the .so file. I just get `Application terminated` message on Android studio's Run terminal.

I get a similar error even if I change some values in section headers without removing them.

AFAIK the section headers are not needed for execution or dynamic loading.
Why does not the App run without section headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allowed to remove those headers ([source](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.html))
:

> Each ELF file has additional information contained in the section headers. These headers must be present now, because the dynamic linker uses them for sanity checking. Some developers try to strip them in an attempt to obfuscate the binary and prevent reverse engineering. (This doesn’t really help because it is possible to reconstruct the stripped information using widely-available tools.)